Page will not load even though a javascript file with its name has been created
I'm new to react and gatsby so I am following the gatsby tutorial online. I was steadily working through Part 2 when I ran into  problem. On the tutorial they have created a second javascript file called about.js and added a basic component and exported it at the end. I did all that, granted I typed it all out myself and changed up the text in the html stuff a little but nothing that should affect the outcome of the program too much. But when I go to http://localhost:8000/about/ I get a 404 error and the gatsby development 404 page. To make things worse at the bottom it has a list of pages that it recognizes and http://.../about/ is one of them. Anyone know what is happening here? I will put the code for the home and about page along with screenshots below.
    import * as React from 'react'
    import { Link } from 'gatsby'

    const IndexPage = () => {
      return (
        <main>
          <h1>This is my header</h1>
          <p>This is my paragraph, WOWZA!</p>  
          <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
        </main>
      )
    }

    export default IndexPage

http://localhost:8000/
    import * as React from 'react'
    import { Link } from 'gatsby'

    const AboutPage = () => {
      return (
        <main>
          <h1>About Me</h1>
          <Link to="/">Back to Home</Link>
          <p>Hi there! I'm the proud creator of this site, which I built with Gatsby.</p>
        </main>
      )
    }

    export const Head = () => <title>About Me</title>

    export default AboutPage

http://localhost:8000/about/
I tried rerunning gatsby develop to see if that did anything but it didn't.

I do not know that framework, but with a quick glance it looks opinionated. If you don't follow their dogma, things probably aren't going to work. Per example, I noticed that the framework serves anything in the pages folder. From your 404 response, it seems that it goes up a level to find about.js. Can you confirm that about.js is located in the pages folder?

yes, the about.js file is in the pages folder

Can you verify that this example matches your code?

looks like it, nothing jumps out to me as different. I can see it works in your environment just fine.

To see the url with /about on web, have to use Route.
Instead of element with function name, can use component with component name.
<Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
<Route path="/about" component={About} />


The tutorial does not introduce the Route concept in it so I'm assuming that it would not be needed in the context of gatsby, is this something from a more default react?

Made a new gatsby build but kept everything the same. This site works as intended and doesn't 404. As of now, I don't know why the issue occurred but am able to keep progressing.
